# Sean Carroll's photons on top of one another

Tags: black-holes, photons, mass-energy, popular-science, bosons

I don't have training in physics, only in mathematics.
The following is a passage from **From Eternity to here** by Sean Carroll, which I wanted to clarify.

> Photons can be piled on top of one another without limit, so we should be able to have as many photons in the box as we wish. From that point of view, the answer seems to be that we can fit an infinite (or at least arbitrarily large) amount of entropy in any given box. There is no upper limit. That story, however, is missing a crucial ingredient: gravity. As we put more and more stuff into the box, the mass inside keeps growing.225 Eventually, the stuff we are putting into the box suffers the same fate as a massive star that has exhausted its nuclear fuel: It collapses under its own gravitational pull and forms a black hole.

There are two parts that I am unsure if I understood properly.

1. The last part, in which if we put sufficient number of photons in a finite volume it produces a gravitational singularity. What I understood is that the energy of the photons corresponds to mass according to $E=mc^2$, and when this mass (sufficient of it) is confined in a finite volume produces the singularity as any other mass would do. Is this correct?
2. The part that I am less sure of its meaning is the first sentence. What does it mean "piled on top of one another"? Does it mean same position? I don't know well how this things are modeled. Is is correct if I understand it as interpreting two photons (say with the same energy) on top of each other as one photon with double the energy? Or could there be two different wave functions, one representing Carroll's two photons one on top of the other and another for one photon with the sum of their energies.

Sorry if the language has imprecisions. I don't have a proper training in the subject.

Comment: It's actually not at all obvious whether the gravitational collapse would produce a black hole, as Carroll says. Models of gravitational collapse often give other results, such as a naked singularity. That is, the cosmic censorship hypothesis appears to be violated for many physically well-motivated examples, and it could be violated for this one. You ask whether it produces a singularity, which is different from the question of whether it produces a black hole. The answer to that is certainly yes, because of the Penrose singularity theorem.

Comment: @BenCrowell Interesting. The concept of naked singularity and the cosmic censorship hypothesis seem quite relevant to the topic of the arrow of time and causality. I wonder why they are not mentioned in Carroll's book.

Comment: What kind of box could hold so many photons?

Comment: Hellen asked: *"Is is correct if I understand it as interpreting two photons on top of each other as one photon with double the energy?"* - No, since a photon has the energy E=hf, so for twice the energy you would need twice the frequency. In your example the energy doubles while the frequency stays the same, so you need twice the photons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes you seem to understand this correctly.
2. The author is using imprecise language here. "Piled on top of each other" means "occupying the same single-particle state". Photons don't obey the Pauli exclusion principle which says that only one particle can be in a given state. For particles obeying Pauli (like electrons), if you put a bunch of them in a system (say a box or an atom) they each need to go into a different state. (This is why in chemistry we have the orbitals all filling up in some order.) Photons by contrast are free to all go into the lowest energy level.

Comment: And to add on to the second comment, while classically, this is equivalent to one photon with double the energy, this is not true quantum mechanically, though to complicate matters, photon number is not a good eigenstate of the QED hamiltonian, either.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer "this is not true quantum mechanically". Does that mean that two photons "occupying the same single particle state" would be represented by one wave function, while a single photon with energy the sum of those two would be represented by a different wave function? Maybe my question doesn't make sense since you are saying that number of photons is not well defined.

Comment: @Hellen: You don't really have the same notion of "wave function" in quantum field theory, but a two-particle state is different than a one-particle state, even if the particles are both in the same state.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer - can you expand on that a little - what way does two photons occupying the same state differ than a single photon with double the energy?